# Get values from hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have hash that looks like this:

```
{"0"=>{"car_addition_id"=>"9"}, "1"=>{"car_addition_id"=>"10"}}
```

I want to get from this hash only this "10" and "9" values in array. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this out:

```
   h = {"0"=>{"car_addition_id"=>"9"}, "1"=>{"car_addition_id"=>"10"}}
   h.map{|k,v| v.values}.flatten
    => ["9", "10"]
```

or as per @gotva

```
   h.flat_map{|k,v| v.values}
```

Comment: This is great and very fast answer. Thanks!

Comment: and you can use [`flat_map`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map) instead of `map` + `flatten`

Answer (score 3):

```
{"0"=>{"car_addition_id"=>"9"}, "1"=>{"car_addition_id"=>"10"}}
.values.flat_map(&:values)
# => ["9", "10"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the values associated with the key `"car_addition_id"` (and not whatever key appears in those locations in the expression), the most straightforward way is:

```
h.map { |_k,v| v["car_addition_id"] }
  #=> ["9", "10"]
```

This of course works if the inner hashes contain multiple key/value pairs.

For those unfamiliar with the notation, `_k` and `_` are both placeholders for an unused block variable; the former can be used to indicate how the block variable would have been written had it been used.